# How to get RouteData.Value in class in ASP.NET webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, webforms, routedata

I am getting route data value in `Page_Load` but I want to get this value in a class.

```
string id = Page.RouteData.Values["id"]; // works in Page_Load
```

I have tried this code in a class but it didn't work. It's returning null. I don't want to check in `Page_Load()` on every page. I just want to check using a function in a class if it's possible.

```
RouteData routeData = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;

if(routeData != null)
{
    var id = routeData.Values["id"];
}
else
{
    // Routedata returning null;
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: You should pass `HttpContext` as a parameter instead of using `HttpContext.Current`.

Comment: How can i handle HttpContext in Global.asax do you have an idea? @Dai